# Pushing an array to an environment variable in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have the following code in Postman Test. I am trying to extract from a JSON some values. However they are not posted in the environment variables.

```
pm.test("Extract Projects", function () {

    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var aDataEntry = [];

    for (var i=0;i<jsonData.length;i++){

        if (jsonData[i].projectCategory.name=="External Projects")
        {
          aDataEntry.push(jsonData[i].key);
        }
    }

    console.log('test');

    pm.environment.set('projects',JSON.stringify(aDataEntry));

});
```

Comment: I don't think env variables can be used in this way. Env vars usually are loaded in the system startup and should not change in the execution time.

Comment: You must have an Environment selected from top right dropdown menu to set a variable.

Comment: Show your JSON response

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you wrapped it in a test as it's not really testing anything.

Without seeing the actual response data, you could try this:

```
var jsonData    = pm.response.json();
var aDataEntry  = [];

_.each(jsonData, (arrItem) => {
    if(arrItem.projectCategory.name === "External Projects") {
        aDataEntry.push(arrItem.key);
    }
})

pm.environment.set('projects', JSON.stringify(aDataEntry));
```